# Download SSRS Report and save in specific location (C#) (Unauthorized)

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

**Question**

I am attempting to download an SSRS report via its URL into a data buffer (byte array), so therefore I can then save it in a particular folder, with a name of my choosing. I am open to suggestions of different ways of doing this if required.

**The Issue**

However I am constantly getting the below error **(401) Unauthorized**, no matter which credentials I enter:

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.

I am using this code (C#):

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
myWebClient.Credentials = netCredential;

var theURL = "http://ReportServer/ReportServer_MYSERVER/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fPurchaseOrder&rs:Command=Render&OrderID=100&rs:ClearSession=true&rs:Format=PDF"

byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(theURL);
```

example URL (this downloads the file perfectly if I simply copy the below URL into my browser, no issues with the access whatsoever): `http://ReportServer/ReportServer_MYSERVER/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fPurchaseOrder&rs:Command=Render&OrderID=100&rs:ClearSession=true&rs:Format=PDF`

My machine is on a domain, and I have tried these credentials, along with the domain, and also the database SA account, but both deliver the same issue.

I know this code works when downloading a PDF file, as I hard-coded a random URL from the internet and this worked, for example: "http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf"

Thankyou all for help on this matter, im hoping that this is possible as this would be a very handy addition to my application

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it turns out it was as simple as this for my scenario (using Default Credentials):

```
var theURL = "http://ReportServer/ReportServer_MYSERVER/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fPurchaseOrder&rs:Command=Render&OrderID=100&rs:ClearSession=true&rs:Format=PDF";

WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

byte[] myDataBuffer = Client.DownloadData(theURL);
```

this code above enables any SSRS report to be downloaded as a byte array. This then means that it can be saved in a specified location, with a name of your choice:

```
var filename = "Test.PDF";
var fileStructureLocal = "C:\\Test";
var fileStructureNetwork = "\\\\NetworkDrive\TestFolder";

var fileLocation = fileStructureNetwork + "\\" + filename;

 if (System.IO.File.Exists(url) == true)
        {
            //DO NOTHING
        }
 else
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(url, myDataBuffer);
            //SAVE FILE HERE
        }
```

this next block is how you rename the file, and specify the location. I have also added a check to see if it already exists, if it does it simply does nothing.

I hope this helps as this is something I have been trying to get working for a long time!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote in vb.net using custom authentication as following,

```
     
private sub GenerateReportPDF () 
 Dim username As String = "username"
          Dim password As String = "password"
          Dim strURL As String = $"https://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?Report&param1=" + Param1 + "&Param2=" + Param1 + "&rs:Format=PDF"

          'prepare the request'
          Dim req As WebClient = New WebClient()
          req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
          req.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
          req.UseDefaultCredentials = True

          Dim myCache As New CredentialCache()
          myCache.Add(New Uri($"https://server/reportserver"), "NTLM", New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, "domainName"))
          req.Credentials = myCache

          'prepare the response'
          Dim myResponse As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
          myResponse.Clear()
          myResponse.ClearContent()
          myResponse.ClearHeaders()
          myResponse.Buffer = True
          myResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf"
          myResponse.BinaryWrite(req.DownloadData(strURL))
          myResponse.End()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the **ReportExecutionService** class will be a best alternative solution. The chance of report getting failed to download is very less.

Every Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Server provide an SOAP End-point to **ReportExecutionService**. Third party application can use this extension to get connected to reporting server.

For .Net applications, using Visual Studio we can add Web Reference to the SOAP end-point http://(your_server_url)/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx (ReportExecutionService).

This will generate the necessary namepsaces and classed to the SOAP End-Point, which we can consume in our application to download the reports.

A Sample code is given below. The steps to add Web Reference, common errors and other details on this method can be found at

https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/download-sql-server-reporting-service-ssrs-report-as-pdf-using-c-sharp/

**Note: We do not have NuGet Package or library available to resolve the namespace ReportExecutionService. Adding Web Reference to your Reporting server will resolve this.**

```
using DownloadSSRSReport.craftedforeveryone.com;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace DownloadSSRSReport
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
rs.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
rs.Url = "http://craftedforeveryone.com/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx";

rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
var executionInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
executionInfo = rs.LoadReport("/your report path/report name", null);

List<ParameterValue> parameters = new List<ParameterValue>();

parameters.Add(new ParameterValue { Name = "parameterId", Value = "value" });

rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters.ToArray(), "en-US");


string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string[] streamId;
Warning[] warning;

var result = rs.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out encoding, out warning, out streamId);
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\temp\\report.pdf", result);

}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill certainly have a look into this method, as it does fail occasionally which I have programmed in a work around, but not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, only difference used HTTPClient

```
var theURL = "http://ReportServer/ReportServer_MYSERVER/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fPurchaseOrder&rs:Command=Render&OrderID=100&rs:ClearSession=true&rs:Format=PDF";

var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                                    {
                                        UseDefaultCredentials = true
                                    };

            HttpClient webClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

            byte[] response = await webClient.GetByteArrayAsync(theURL);
```